# How can I instantiate a const typedef pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants, typedef

**The following piece of code:**

```
typedef void* ptr_t;

void func()
{
    const ptr_t ptr; // Line 1
    ptr = ...;       // Line 2
}
```

**Yields the following compilation errors:**

- Line 1, Error C2734 (C++): `const` object must be initialized if not `extern`
- Line 2, Error C3892 (C++): you cannot assign to a variable that is `const`
- Line 2, Error C2166 (C): l-value specifies `const` object

**The reason behind these compilation errors:**

- `const ptr_t ptr` is interpreted as `void* const ptr` instead of `const void* ptr`
- With `void* const ptr`, you cannot change the pointer but you can change the pointed data
- With `const void* ptr`, you can change the pointer but you cannot change the pointed data

---

My goal here is to prevent possible attempts to change the contents of the memory pointed by `ptr`.

I can work-around this problem using `#define ptr_t void*` instead of `typedef void* ptr_t`.

But it doesn't feel like a proper solution in terms of coding correctness. Is there any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Not use pointer for strings at all? In C++ there is [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), use it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `char*` is just an example. You can think of `int*`, `void*` or any other type of pointer. I'll edit the question in order to make it clearer...

Comment: "Work around this problem"?!? What exactly is the problem? You seem to understand how typedefs work; what problem needs to be solved here? If you want a const char pointer, just say `const char * str;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's a little more complicated than the simple example given here. It's `typedef` of another `typedef` of another `typedef` etc., used in various places within the code.

Comment: If you absolutely want to use type-aliases, you should know that they can often make your code less readable, and therefore less maintainable. And to solve your problem, why not use *two* type-aliases? One for pointers to constant data, and one for non-constant?

Comment: From the way the question is written I have absolutely no idea what your actual question and/or problem is and which solution would satisfy you. There are several obvious C++ type trait manipulations, but it's impossible to tell whether that's what you're after.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Any "non-preprocessor" solution would be great.

Comment: try typedef const char* str;

Comment: @barakmanos: You keep saying the word "solution". I have no idea what you're trying to solve!

Comment: @mohaned: Thanks, but then I have to declare two different `typedef`s.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Cannot instantiate `const ptr_t ptr`.

Comment: @barakmanos: Remove the `const`: `ptr_t ptr;` Done.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Then someone might attempt to change the pointed memory.

Comment: You might want to read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What your question is about is "I have this solution I want to use, how to make it work?", but you don't actually state the problem that the solution is intended to solve.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I would like to declare `const ptr_t ptr`, in order to prevent possible attempts to change the contents of the memory pointed by `ptr`.

Comment: @barakmanos "Then someone might attempt to change the pointed memory" - such was the choice to declare `ptr_t` as a non-const pointer type. Nothing outside preprocessor hoops is going to solve that, and that not likely either, as other users of `ptr_t` may well expect (and in the case of decorated library exports, *demand*) it be non-const.

Comment: @WhozCraig: "Nothing outside preprocessor hoops is going to solve that" is also an answer to my question "Is there any alternative?", I just need to know. Any idea what was the motivation behind making `typedef` "behave" in such an awkward and unpredictable manner?

Comment: @barakmanos i occasionally wonder the same thing, but ultimately it makes sense to me, as it drives home the specificity requirements at the time the type alias is declared. Chris has a similar question about a year ago about promoting const-correctness through a similar situation (more const is always better, right ? =), and the limitations encountered therein, this being one of them. I'd have to hunt for the question, but it was long the same lines with similar response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a C++ solution to turn a pointer-to-object into a pointer-to-const-object:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using more_const_ptr = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_pointer<T>::value,
    typename std::add_pointer<
        typename std::add_const<
            typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type>::type>::type;
```

Usage:

```
using p = int *;    // or "typedef int * p;" in C++03

int a = 10;
more_const_ptr<p> q = &a;
// *q = 20;  // Error, q is "const int *"
```

---

(In C++14 there are useful shortcuts that make this more readable:)

```
template <typename T>
using more_const_ptr = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_pointer<T>::value,
    std::add_pointer_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>>;
```

Comment: +1 (both you and Benjamin, actually). That 4-pack of `::type` in that decl... *awesome*.

Comment: @T.C.: The purpose of the comment is to explain the analogy to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

In line 1, as you say you have a pointer type and then make it const. This means you have a constant pointer to (non-constant) data. Declaring it as `type const` won't solve anything, because C specifies that such a declaration is equivalent to `const type`.

There is no work-around. Generally, it is a bad idea to hide a pointer underneath a typedef. This makes the code very hard to read, even if you have a coding standard for variable naming. Just look at the Windows API for a perfect example of how to turn the C language into something less readable.

So the quick & dirty solution is to keep digging your hole deeper by declaring a `typedef const void* cptr_t;`. Or indeed use a macro, it is an equally bad solution.

The good solution is to forget all about hiding pointers behind typedefs and other such attempts to change the well-known C or C++ language into some mysterious, personal macro language.

Comment: Funny that you mention "Windows API", as that is **exactly** where my problem stems from (type `BSTR` to be more accurate, in case you've heard of it)...

Comment: @barakmanos You can always "fix" Win API code. In the case of BSTR, don't use it in your own code, use `OLECHAR*` instead, and that might solve the whole problem.

Comment: And therefore, as you can probably understand, it is not exactly my choice to "forget all about hiding pointers behind typedefs" at this point...

Comment: Yes, well using `OLECHAR*` instead of `BSTR` **has** occurred to me... But `BSTR` is a well known type, so I was hoping I could keep using it as is.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <type_traits>
...
typedef std::remove_pointer<ptr_t>::type base_type;
typedef base_type const* const_ptr_t;
```

If `ptr_t` is actually a template parameter, rather than a concrete type, then you will need to throw a `typename` in there:

```
typedef typename std::remove_pointer<ptr_t>::type base_type;
```

Comment: Thank you. Will I be able to use both `ptr_t` and `const ptr_t`?

Comment: @barakmanos: What do you mean, exactly? You will be able to use them, but It won't do what you want, if I am understanding correctly what it is that you want.

Comment: So `const ptr_t` will not be equivalent to `const void*` then?

Comment: @barakmanos: No, of course not. `const_ptr_t` will be though, if you use the typedefs I showed.

Comment: Oh, so it's essentially the same as if I would have declared two different `typedef`s - one with `const` and one without `const`, right?